# Paging Trogdor for the [page] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [page](/questions/tagged/page) tag is all over the map. There are many questions where it means a web page, often a Facebook page. Sometimes it means scrolling through a long text. Sometimes it means virtual memory. Glancing at the questions, there seems to be some other relevant tag, most of the time ([html](/questions/tagged/html), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), [memory](/questions/tagged/memory), …). The questions in this tag don't look markedly worse than average (just perhaps a tad badly tagged). All in all, [page](/questions/tagged/page) looks like a prime candidate for burnination.

Is there any reason for retaining the [page](/questions/tagged/page) tag, at least temporarily, that I've missed? Otherwise, the tag should be removed and blacklisted.

Comment: most of those are created thanks to people who think that separated tags make sense if they are close to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]